# Android: Elipsoid Altitude to Metres over Sea

Tags: android, gps, altitude

I know that when I use `.getAltitude()` I get the height above the WGS84 reference ellipsoid. Now, there is an inaccuracy of more than 50 metres.

Furthermore, I know that the height can not be calculated so easy to the normal metres over sea. 
In my app, I can´t give the user such an inaccuracy. How can I handle that? Is there only the one way that I use a Web Service to get the exact height?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer only a part of your question:

The GPS chip delivers the height above the WGS84 ellipsoid, but still usually this value is inacurate by typically 20-30m. So even the value related to the elliposid is wrong.

For an accurate height you must

1. Correct the inacurate altitude (WGS84 ellipsoid) to the correct WGS84 height by using a web Service, where you send you lat,lon coordinates to.
2. Convert the now acccurate height above WGS84 to height above mean Sea-level.

For point 2, I am not sure if there is a service and if you can do it locally.

I recomend that you read this post: [How do I convert a geodetic location to an ECF position that works with the terrain model in Cesium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299154/how-do-i-convert-a-geodetic-location-to-an-ecf-position-that-works-with-the-terr/16299846#16299846)

**Update:**
Every GPS receiver can output height above mean sea level and height above ellipsoid,  this means that there is a possibilty to convert without using much memory.
Find out how they do, and please post here. (Add a comment if you found out)
(The GPS NMEA GGA message contains both values)

Comment: When I´m not complete wrong, point 2. isn´t possible.
But thanks for your annwer!

Comment: Updated, more info at the provide link

Comment: Update2: evry GPS chip can output both mena sea level, and above ellipsoid.